# Missing header in aastex package

Tags: header-footer, aastex

I'm using the `aastex` package `(v5.2)`, and trying to make a header appear using the `\shorttitle` and `\shortauthors` commands (which take the place of `\leftheader` `\rightheader`), but they aren't working for me.  Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,preprint]{aastex}
\usepackage[left=1in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}

\shorttitle{short title}
\shortauthors{short author}
\begin{document}
\title{Long Title}
\author{Long Author}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{abstract}
Test
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Text
\newpage
New page test
\end{document}
```

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: `page 3` of the `aastex` manual: "*This running head information will not appear on the LATEX-printed page but will be
passed through to copy editing staff for inclusion
in the published version*."

Comment: Wow, thanks, that's really weird... Any idea how to get headers running that I **can** see?

Comment: Using `aastex` only without additional packages? Not really. That involves redefining some macros and, truth to tell, I've been trying just for the fun of it. But I can't make it work. Maybe some tex guru will take a look at it later. Try `fancyhdr` if that is an option. I have to ask, why do you want to see the headers? IMHO if you submit your paper to AAS, they might not want to see the headers already printed. :)

Comment: Awesome, `fancyhdr` works fine!  Its for a random proposal (with no specified stylefile), and I just like the aastex style.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the `plaintop` page style that's used with the `preprint` option:

```
\makeatletter
\def\ps@plaintop{%
 \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
 \def\@oddfoot{}%
 \def\@evenfoot{}%
 \def\@oddhead{%
   \rmfamily\hfil\@rectohead\ --\ \@versohead\hfil\llap{\thepage}}%
 \let\@evenhead\@oddhead
}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{plaintop}
```

Modify to suit

Answer (score 1):

**hpesoj626** points out that the running headers from `\shorttitle` and `\shortauthors` don't actually appear on the document... for whatever reasons.  As per his recommendation, I'm using the `fancyhdr` package --- which is working nicely.